How to ignore cmake '-fpermissive' warning？
Due to issues in the underlying framework that cannot be modified, there are a large number of -fpermissive warnings, which interfere with the judgment of other information. How can I modify the configuration in CMakeLists.txt to ignore only this warning while keeping other warnings visible? (Environment: RedHat + GCC 4.9.4)
I once looked up using the -Wno-address-of-temporary option online, but the error says that the option is not supported.

-fpermissive does not enable warnings, it disables hard errors and turns them to warnings. It isn't clear why you want to de-prioritise those in favour of less serious ones.
